# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to update a record in the database but I get an error I can't solve.

```cs
public async Task<bool> AddUpdateAsync(Activity objActivity)
{
    try
    {

        using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            if (objActivity.Id == 0)
            {
                // CODE TO ADD NEW HERE
            }
            else
            {
                var DbActivity = await GetByIdAsync(objActivity.Id);

                PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Activity).GetProperties();
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    property.SetValue(DbActivity, property.GetValue(objActivity));
                }

                _db.Update(DbActivity);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public async Task<Activity> GetByIdAsync(int Id)
{
    using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        return await _db.Activities.Include(x => x.Room).Include(x => x.Debtor).SingleAsync(x => x.Id == Id);
    }
}
```

**Error:**
The instance of entity type 'Activity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

Anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Remove `_db.Update(DbActivity);`

Comment: FYI you can use `_db.Entry(DbActivity).CurrentValues.SetValues(objActivity)` in place of your own Reflection and foreach loop to accomplish property mapping.

Comment: [DbContext.Update method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0) begins tracking the given entity. So you must not call this method.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov without `_db.Update(DbActivity);` nothing is saved to the database

Comment: Do not use reflection - it breaks change tracking. Try what Valuator suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same instance of your context, so in the parameters of your **GetByIdAsync** method You should add your db context also:

```
 public async Task<Activity> GetByIdAsync(YourDbContext _db, int Id)
 {
     return await _db.Activities.Include(x => x.Room).Include(x => x.Debtor).SingleAsync(x => x.Id == Id);
 }
```

or make it **public**, declaring it outside of all your methods:

```
public YourDbContext _Db;
```

and using @Valuator advice also, the right version of your method should be:

```
public async Task<bool> AddUpdateAsync(Activity objActivity)
{
    try
    {

        using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            if (objActivity.Id == 0)
            {
                // CODE TO ADD NEW HERE
            }
            else
            {
                var DbActivity = await GetByIdAsync(YourDbContext _db, objActivity.Id);
                _db.Entry(DbActivity).CurrentValues.SetValues(objActivity);
                _db.Entry(DbActivity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _db.Update(DbActivity);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed my `foreach` and using `_db.Entry(DbActivity).CurrentValues.SetValues(objActivity);` now. Also added `_db.Entry(DbActivity).State = EntityState.Modified;` between `SetValues` and `_db.Update`. Works like it should now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering, "The instance of entity type 'Activity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked," occurs because Entity Framework Core is trying to track multiple instances of the same entity with the same primary key (`Id`) within the same `DbContext`. This can happen if you've already loaded an instance of `Activity` with the same `Id` elsewhere in your code.

To fix this issue, you can detach the existing `DbActivity` from the context before attaching the updated one. Here's how you can modify your code to do that:

```
public async Task<bool> AddUpdateAsync(Activity objActivity)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _db = _factory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            if (objActivity.Id == 0)
            {
                // CODE TO ADD NEW HERE
            }
            else
            {
                var DbActivity = await GetByIdAsync(objActivity.Id);

                PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Activity).GetProperties();
                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    property.SetValue(DbActivity, property.GetValue(objActivity));
                }

                // Detach the existing entity from the context
                _db.Entry(DbActivity).State = EntityState.Detached;

                // Attach the updated entity
                _db.Update(DbActivity);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `_db.Update(DbActivity);`. [DbContext.Update method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-7.0) begins tracking the given entity. So you must not call this method.

Comment: Also remove `_db.Entry(DbActivity).State = EntityState.Detached;`

Comment: This does not work

Comment: This answer has a hint of AI-generation.