EF Core Update Successful But throws an Exception in Update
I am reading a CategoryType object from the database (in a controller method for update).
CategoryType  categoryType1 = await CategoryType.GetById(databaseService, ID, UserId);

And then update the object properties based on the users input;
categoryType1.Name     = Name;
categoryType1.Status   = Status;

Then the object is passed to the database service class to update it in the database
public async Task<int> UpdateCategoryType(CategoryType newCategoryType)
{
  int         result                          = -1;

   try
   {
      CategoryType categoryType = new (newCategoryType.ID, newCategoryType.Name, newCategoryType.IconName, newCategoryType.FriendlyName, newCategoryType.Status, newCategoryType.UserId, newCategoryType.IsDefaultImage);
      var updated = appDbContext.Update(categoryType);
      await appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
      result                                  = updated.Entity.ID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       result                                  = -1;
       string  message             = ex.Message ?? string.Empty;
       string  stackTraceInfo      = ex.StackTrace ?? string.Empty;
       ApplicationLog applicationLog  = new(Constants.APPLICATION_LOG_ERROR, "DatabaseService", "UpdateCategoryType", message, stackTraceInfo);

       if (applicationLog != null)
       {
           await SaveApplicationLog(applicationLog);
       }                
  }            

  return result;
}

The update method (appDbContext.Update) get succeeded, as I can see in the database the object is correctly updated with the passed values (as an example change in the name).
But for some reason an exception is thrown as well.
Below is the exception message that is thrown;
The instance of entity type 'CategoryType' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

and the following is the stacktrace of the exception (DatabaseService.cs:line 288 is the appDbContext.Update method);
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Update[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at GroceryCostTracker.WebApi.Services.DatabaseService.UpdateCategoryType(CategoryType newCategoryType) in DatabaseService.cs:line 288

I am not sure what is happening in here. Would like to get help in rectifying the issue.

This is answered correctly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77182212/the-instance-of-entity-type-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-with-the
